# Simple memcpy doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memcpy

I am trying to do a simple memcpy as below.

```
char *token[32];
char *temp_store[4];

for (i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)
{
   memcpy(token[4+i],temp_store[i],strlen(temp_store[i]));
}
```

I have the following values inside the token array.

```
temp_store[0] = "5";
temp_store[1] = "6";
temp_store[2] = "7";
temp_store[3] = "8";
```

I want these 4 values `"5" , "6",  "7",  "8"` to be copied to `token[4],token[5],token[6] and token[7]` respectively.

However I am not getting those values in token[] for some reason.I can't figure out why that is.

Comment: is `temp_store[i]` a C-string?

Comment: For what you are doing, I recommend using strcat.  Also, have you confirmed that temp_store is ok?  How did you initialize it?  There could be a problem with that to begin with.

Comment: `token[4+i]` and `temp_store[i]` are uninitialized. Also, "doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering just what the OP is trying to do.  The declaration of token followed by the indexing looks really suspicious.

Comment: Well doesn't work means the values inside token[] is same as before copying.

Comment: The temp_store is properly initialized to the values mentioned above.I have put a printf statement to check that.

Comment: @liv2hak: If your program is short, please post the whole thing.

Comment: An example of how this code is called would be quite useful.  This shows a clear misunderstanding of how pointers, arrays and strings work in C, and as a result this code is confusing the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  However, if you're just trying to concatenate a string, memcpy is not the way to go.  Use strcat, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    strcat(token[i+4], temp_store[i]);
}
```

If you are going to do string operations, use null terminated strings and the str* functions.  C has support for those, and many of the string operations you'll want (concatenation, length, duplication with allocation, comparison) are in the suite, plus they're less cumbersome to use than mem* functions.

Comment: you mean strcat(token[4+i],temp_store[i]); I have 4 string already in token.I don't want them to be overwritten.

Comment: Well, the above was just a sample, but I edited it to reflect what you want :)

Comment: @AndryT: I think by copy, the OP meant concatenate.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you want to copy a C-string using `memcpy` function, you have to copy `strlen() + 1` bytes to include the zero terminator character. Or you have to add that terminating zero to the destination array yourself. Without a terminating zero it is not a string.

Secondly, copying zero-terminating strings is actually what `strcpy` function does. Why did you choose to use `memcpy` instead?

Thirdly, if you really want to duplicate the source strings, did you remember to allocate the destination memory before performing the copying? Show us how you allocated it. The code you posted so far does not allocate that memory, meaning that your `memcpy` call copies the data "into nowhere", leading to undefined behavior usually resulting in a crash.

Fourthly, are you sure you want to duplicate these strings as opposed to simply making the `token[]` elements to point to the same memory locations? The latter can be achieved by simple

```
token[4+i] = temp_store[i];
```

Whether this approach is applicable in your case depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here each of temp_store[0],temp_store[1],temp_store[2],temp_store[3] is a pointer to a char array.
You need to make sure these four char arrays are null-ended.

strlen() is use to determine the length of a string that is null-ended

Another way to content of multiple array into a larger array is using memcpy like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const int LEN = 10 ;
    const int NUM_STRING = 4 ;
    char token[NUM_STRING*LEN+1]={0};
    char temp_store[NUM_STRING][LEN] = { {0} };

    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_STRING; i++) {
        memcpy(token+LEN*i, temp_store[i], sizeof(temp_store[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this would copy whole of temp_store[0], temp_store[1], temp_store[2], temp_store[3] into token

(That mean all of the 10*4 characters in temp_store[4][10])

Comment: I see your point.the arrays are not null ended.How do I calculate the length without using the strlen().Is there some other function that calculates the size.?

Comment: @liv2hak: If you are using strings, use null terminated ones.  C functions are designed to support those; why make your life more difficult?